# How can I show immediate and/or parents in a title?

Tags: functions

I use a function to modify titles of various pages.

Although it appears to work, it shows a debug error of... Notice: Undefined variable: parents_titles line xxx.

It'll be because of my 'little knowledge, dangerous thing' uninformed tampering of whatever source I began with.

What changes does it need?

```
function change_wp_title( $title ) {
    global $post, $paged;

    // All parents.
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $key => $parentpost ) {
        $postdata = get_post( $parentpost );
        $parents_titles .= $postdata->post_title . ' : ';
    }

    $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent) . ': ';

    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title['title'] = 'file not available';
    } 
    elseif ( 4808 == $post->post_parent ) {
        $title['title'] = 'About: Who: ' . $parent_title . $title['title'];
    }

    // Various conditionals for other pages.

    else {
        $title['title'] = $parents_titles . $title['title'];
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'change_wp_title', 20, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize your variable $parents_titles before the foreach

```
$parents_titles = '';
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know enough to understand your advice, and am currently searching. If you're able to explain further it'll be a help to me.

Comment: In your code, `$parents_titles` gets set inside your `$foreach()` loop. But if the `$parents` array is empty, that `foreach()` won't do anything. Thus, `$parents_titles` will be un-initialized. What @Nouniz suggests in this answer is to [initialize `$parents_titles` as an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9037383/1094518) (ie, `''`) *before* your `foreach()` loop, so that, even if `parents` is empty, your `$parents_titles` string will have *something* in it.

Comment: @Pat J Thanks. I'll try to understand this better this in the morning when I've a clear head. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Notice in your code is caused by undefined variable. But there are some more things that could be done a little bit nicer...

```
function change_wp_title( $title ) {
    global $post, $paged;

    if ( is_404() ) {  // move this check here; if it's 404, there is no point in checking parents, ancestors, and so on
        $title['title'] = 'file not available';
        return $title;
    }

    $parent_title = $parents_titles = '';  // initialise titles with empty string

    // All parents.
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    if ( ! empty($parents) ) {  // check if $parents is not empty
        foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $key => $parentpost ) {
            $parents_titles .= get_post_field( 'post_title', $parentpost ) . ' : ';  // You don't have to get all fields for given post
        }
    }

    if ( $post->post_parent ) {  // check if there is parent
        $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent) . ': ';
    }


    if ( 4808 == $post->post_parent ) {
        $title['title'] = 'About: Who: ' . $parent_title . $title['title'];
    }

    // Various conditionals for other pages.

    else {
        $title['title'] = $parents_titles . $title['title'];
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'change_wp_title', 20, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll get to this in the morning when I've a clear head. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the fix - although I can only get it to work if  the 404 condition is after '// check if there is parent' code.